# Map rails belongs_to relation to elacticsearch for search by nested object and pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

In my rails project I have two models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :homeworks   
  ...
end

class Homework < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  attr_accessible :grade
  belongs_to :student
  ...
end
```

I want to run a query on the elasticsearch side of things:

1. Find all students with at least one 'F' grade for homework.
2. Sort students

   - by count of homeworks rated 'F'
   - by name
3. Paginate students

This simplified example can be solved without utilizing elasticsearch, however the project I am working on has a full text search functionality which requires elasticsearch.

I tried the following approaches:

1. Storing attributes of the parent object inside the child objects and use facets for grouping. This seems to work but then I can't paginate my results as described here: http://bit.ly/10hyYoS
2. Using nested documents. My search query returns filtered students with all unfiltered homework and I am not sure how to filter children in the search results.

I would appreciate an advice on how to map these models to elasticsearch and execute the queries efficiently.

Not asking for a complete solution, just a general sense of direction. Should I use nested objects?  Store attributes of student inside homework and use facets for grouping?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar use case I have used the _parent mapping such that homework has a mapping attribute for:

```
"_parent": "student"
```

Then I do a regular query:

```
"query":{ 
  "filtered":{
    "filter": {
     "and": [{
       "term": {"_type": "student"},    
       "has_child": {
          "query":{
             "filtered":{
               "filter":{
                 "term":{"grade", "value"}
              ...
```

(this is not tested, except in a similar query for another project)

The filtered query of has_child is the important part, since that allows you to search on students that have homework with a grade F and include them in your facet.

You will then need to extend the filter clause to include the rest of your query terms and pagination. The filtered query limits the documents used by the facet, so you may then choose to additionally filter by something like a created_at field, or something else, therefore limiting the results you are using.

Comment: Phil, thank you for answer. I figured out how to sort by count, the only thing that's missing is pagination. Any guidance on that would be super helpful!

Comment: Peter, I'm guessing the pagination issue is not as easy as using from/size described here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size/ ... although I've not tried it, my assumption is that it doesn't helpfully reduce the facet. If not, I'd look at maybe paginating by initial letter of name or some other form that helps limit the result set intuitively based on your app.